# Symfony2 Creating a dynamc link with database parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

i got data from the database via $.ajax. But how can i create a link ?

this is my ajax call and the result works:

```
var $resultDepartment = $( '#resultDepartment' );
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: url2,
            data: "locationid=" + locationid,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (resp) {
                for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                    var $link = "{{ path('_niederlassung', {filiale: resp[i].bezeichnung}) }}";
                    console.log($link);
                    $resultDepartment.html("Your Department:<br><br>" + resp[i].bezeichnung) + "<br><br><a href='" + $link + "'>weiter zur Filiale</a>";
                }
            }
        });
```

When i place {{ path('_niederlassung', {filiale: 'exampledepartment'}) }} into the twig, it will be rendered perfect and also work perfect.

Here i show you the route:

```
_niederlassung:
path:  /niederlassung/{filiale}
defaults: { _controller:  MbsNiederlassungBundle:Default:index, filiale: "all" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 solutions :

**1) Returning the route via the action**

// action :

```
return new Response(json_encode(array(
    // here what you want ...
    'link' => $this->generateUrl('_niederlassung', array('filiale' => resp->getBezeichnung())),
)));
```

// JS callback

```
for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
    var $link = resp[i].link // Get the link with ease
}
```

**2) Using FOSJsRoutingBundle**

A bundle to generate URL in JS : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

**3) Url replacement with JS** (valid HTML)

Make a div (or another html element) containing some parameters to pass to JS :

```
<div id="js_config"
    data-filiale-url-prototype="{{ path('_niederlassung', {filiale: 'prototype'}) }}"
>
</div>
```

// Your JS callback :

```
// ...

var urlPrototype = $('#js_config').attr('data-filiale-url-prototype');

for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
    // ...
    var $link = urlPrototype.replace(/prototype/g, resp[i].bezeichnung);
}
```

This is a tehchnical used in one of the Sf2 [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) (search "replace" with ctrl + f in the page).

Choose your favorite solution !